# I am getting this error Error: Incorrect time value: '16:44:09 PM' for column 'time' at row 1 and I'm not sure why

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

This is my php code i am running.
In my server i have a time variable set up to take in time.

```
$time = date('H:i:s A', time());
$query = "INSERT INTO shouts (user, message, time)
VALUES('$user', '$message', '$time')";

if(!mysqli_query($con, $query)){
 die('Error: ' .mysqli_error($con));
}else{
 header("Location: index.php");
 exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the "A" in your time format:

```
$time = date('H:i:s');
```

You also don't really need the second parameter if you are using the current time.

Comment: Thanks that worked. By removing the "A" it removes the pm/am, how would i go about adding that back in?

Comment: When you retrieve the time from the database, you can add the am/pm back like this: <?php echo date('h:i:s a', strtotime($row['time'])); ?>